# how to check the id available in the table column have prefix value in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm using codeigniter for my project. I've store the member id in the member table. Member Id Pattern is "KZI22M8547". Last 4 digits are random, rest of the characters are generated depend upon the form inputs values. I want to check whether the new member id (contains random number for the last 4 digits) is available while creating the new members.

```
I'm using the following code in the model
$query = $this->db->get_where('members', array(
            'member_id' => $member_id
        ));
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Do you want to check it in the SQL query or on the PHP side?

If SQL is WHERE member_id LIKE '%9999' might be the solution. 

If PHP I recommend the function substr() -> https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Comment: currently i'm using the sbstr function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$this->db->select('SUBSTRING(member_id, 7) as member_id', FALSE);
$query = $this->db->get_where('members', array(
    'ch_id' => $ch_id
))->result();

if (in_array($rand_no, array_column($query, 'member_id'))) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```